# Shower head pipe sounds like the toilet is running

Tags: plumbing, water

You know the sound it makes that low running noise when your toilet tank is filling after you flush it?

I'm hearing that constant sound coming from the pipe holding my shower head.

I turned off the air conditioner, hot water heater and still hear it.

It never stops and started a few days ago.

I have no idea what to do next for troubleshooting to figure out what the problem could be.

Comment: Is this a single family home?  How old is it?  What type of pipes?  What country? What climate?

Comment: is the hose outside left on and running?  is there water in your basement/crawlspace? Have you turned off the main water supply valve to your house to see if it stops?

Comment: @tyson Yes single family home, 75 years old ranch, pvp and brass pipes in the Southeast US.

Comment: @Alaskaman There is water in my barn outside but I thought it might be from all the rain we've had but it hasn't dried in 3 days. I wonder if it's related now you mention it.

Comment: With all water consumption turned off, does the water meter show usage?